# HTTP REFERER not receiving in private window of Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, browser, http-referer

I am working on a PHP project. It's working fine in normal window of any browser. Somehow in private window of Chrome i am not able to get HTTP_REFERER 
. The request is initiated from some another domain. So i faced issue during cross domain redirection. Both domains are using "https".

```
Using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] to get referer
```

> Example:- first url is: https://example.com
>   After some checks
>   redirected to: https://seconddomain.com
>   And expecting
>   "https://example.com" as referer on "https://seconddomain.com" domain.

Comment: *"**Somehow** in private window of Chrome i am not able to get HTTP_REFERER."* Seems to me that that is the purpose of using the private/incognito window. To keep information like that private.

Comment: Did somebody got the solution to this? I am getting redirected to same page when using safari in private mode. It is working fine for normal window.